# Exim.conf Redirect email to an another folder

Tags: linux, email, bash, exim

I am trying to redirect/route incoming emails to another folder depending if they are listed inside the /etc/email_list file (ON/OFF). I am unsure how would I approach this, I am clearly messing something up. What would be the correct way of approaching this? Thanks!

Here is my exim.conf

```
custom_folder_redirect:
   driver = redirect

# Check if the email address is listed in /etc/email_list. If yes, folder_redirect = true.

   condition = ${if exists{/etc/email_list} {${lookup{$local_part@$domain} 
   lsearch{/etc/email_list}}}}} {}
   set folder_redirect = true
   message = Your email will be redirected to OTHER_FOLDER folder.

#If the folder redirect is OFF, then redirect the mails to INBOX(cur folder)
   driver = redirect
   condition = ${if !eq{$folder_redirect}{true}}
   data = /$home/mail/$domain/$local_part/cur
   allow_fail
   file_transport = address_file
   pipe_transport = address_pipe
   unseen
   endif

# If the folder redirect is ON, redirect the mails to OTHER_FOLDER
   condition = ${if eq{$folder_redirect}{true}}
   data = /$home/mail/$domain/$local_part/OTHER_FOLDER
   allow_fail
   file_transport = address_file
   pipe_transport = address_pipe
   unseen
   endif
```